# Search-bar shorter than rest of website?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on this website of mine. I notice that the greysofa.html page's search-bar is shorter than the rest of the other pages on my site. However, I can't figure out why this is happening as most of the code is the same throughout the rest of the site. Can someone point out to me which portions I need to amend? Thanks!

https://helloyellowmellowcello.github.io/WareHouse/greysofa.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have imported `cart.css` in `greysofa.html` file, which has this class:

```
input {
    width: 3rem;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    margin-left: 1rem;
}
```

This affects all inputs rendered in the page, including your search bar, which is:

```
<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search for items">
```

`margin-left: 1rem` causes the search bar to be 1rem shorter.

Comment: Thank you for the code review! I was away on a boot camp and didn't see this till today. Let me try to implement this later today and get back to you!

Comment: Glad I could help :]